# LimeSurvey - Inserting first ranked answer in the text of the next question

Tags: java, limesurvey

I have question being a ranked question of top 3,

Q1. PLEASE LIST top 3 supermarkets.

Q2. Why did you choose ?

I know some coding in regards to the single question but have no idea for the ranked question, this is just a personal project.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If your question code are RANK : {RANK_1.shown} sho the text of the 1st option.

See https://manual.limesurvey.org/Expression_Manager#Qcode_Variable_Naming